# Having problems with 0x0A character in C++ even in binary mode. (interprets it as new file)

Tags: c++, binary, hex, fstream, eof

Hi this might seem a bit noobie, but here we go. Im developing a program that downloads leaderboards of a certain game from the internet and transforms it into a proper format to work with it (elaborate rankings, etc).

The files contains the names, ordered by rank, but between each name there are 7 random **control codes** (obivously unprintable). The txt file looks like this:

..C...hName1..)...&Name2......)Name3..é...þName4..Ü...†Name5..‘...QName6..~...bName7..H...NName8..|....Name9..v...HName10.

Checked via an hexEditor and saw the first control code after each name is always a null character (**0x00**). So, what I do is read everything, and then cout every character. When a 0x00 character is found, skip **7** characters and keep couting. Therefore you end up with the list, right?

At first I had the problem that on those random control codes, sometimes you would find like a "soft EOF" (**0x1A**), and the program would stop reading there. So I finally figured out to open it in **binary mode**. It worked, and then everything would be couted... or thats what I thought.

But I came across another file which still didn't work, and finally found out that there was an **EOF** character! (**0x0A**) Which doesn't makes sense since Im opening it in binary mode. But still, after reading that character, C++ interprets that as a new file, and hence skips 7 characters, so the name after that character will always appear cut.

Here's my current code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main () {
  string scores;
  system("wget http://certainwebsite/001.txt"); //download file
  ifstream highin ("001.txt", ios::binary);
  ofstream highout ("board.txt", ios::binary);
  if (highin.is_open())
  {
    while ( highin.good() )
    {
          getline (highin, scores);
          for (int i=0;i<scores.length(); i++)
          {
              if (scores[i]==0x00){
                 i=i+7; //skip 7 characters if 'null' is found
                 cout << endl;
                 highout << endl;
                 }
              cout << scores[i];
              highout << scores[i]; //cout names and save them in output file
          }
    }
    highin.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
  system("pause>nul");
}
```

Not sure how to ignore that character if being already in binary mode doesn't work. Sorry for the long question but I wanted to be detailed and specific. In this case, the EOF character is located before the Name3, and hence this is how the output looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM1Cg.png

Comment: Be careful when incrementing i, it could go past score’s end if the buffer is shorter than expected... looks like getline is the problem. Try using istreams unformatted input functions

Comment: 0x0A is not an "EOF character". It's the end-of-line character, ASCII LF or '\n'. `getline()` recognizes it as an end-of-line marker. If you don't want to treat '\n' characters specially, `getline` is probably the wrong function to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `getline()` reads until the end of line and discards the newline character. However, the delimiter character could be customized (by supplying the third parameter). If you wish to read until the null character (not until the end of line), you could try using `getline (highin, scores, '\0');` (and adjusting the logic of skipping the characters).

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you figured it out and it doesn't surprise me that getline() was the culprit. I had a similar issue dealing with the newline character when I was trying to read in a CSV file. There are several different getline() functions in C++ depending on how you call the function and each seems to handle the newline character differently.

As a side note, in your for loop, I'd recommend against performing a method call in your test. That adds unnecessary overhead to the loop. It'd be better to call the method once and put that value into a variable, then enter the loop and test i against the length variable.  Unless you expect the length to change, calling the length() method each iteration is a waste of system resources.

Comment: Oh I hadn't considered that, thanks for the tip. It's now implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys, it worked, it was the getline() which was giving me problems indeed. Due to the 'while' loop, each time it found a new line character, it restarted the process, hence skipping those 7 characters.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should accept [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762099/having-problems-with-0x0a-character-in-c-even-in-binary-mode-interprets-it-a/16762316#16762316) answer if it was helpful for you. Otherwise you should provide a little more detailed answer explaining your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I still hadn't got familiarized with the accepting answers feature, but now I am ;) Accepted.